# C# pick a random item from a Queue

Tags: c#

I wonder if it is possible to get a random item out of a queue?

```
Queue karten = new Queue();
        karten.Enqueue("Card 1");
        karten.Enqueue("Card 2");
        karten.Enqueue("Card 3");

        foreach(var x in karten)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(x);
        }
```

Comment: If you want to dequeue item from a random place then you should choose different data structure than queue.

Comment: Okey thanks, I will try something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are fundamentally missing the basics of OOP: use the appropriate data type for your purpose, and don't complicate stuff.

```
List<string> list = new List<string>(); //this is an Array List
list.Add("One");
list.Add("Two");
list.Add("Three");

list.RemoveAt(new Random().Next(0, list.Length - 1));
```

If you need to access an item in possibly any place, you must use an array or array-backed list (as the C# `List<T>`), which has O(1) complexity in accessing an element but O(n) in removal. A Linked List has O(n) access to find an element and then O(1) in removing the item you just found.

It means that if you use an array it takes a constant time to find an element by its index, but then you must shift the subsequent elements by one place. For the linked list, conversely, if you hold a reference to *the* item you want to remove, you take constant time in removing it. Of course, if you only know its position it takes O(n) to find the correct item first

Here we are using a random input to remove the item. In real life, you would expect a user input for choosing the item to remove: since that is not under your control, this falls into the `random` approach, where Array List succeeds

Comment: "*While Queues and Stacks are fundamentally implementations of a LinkedList*" -- no they're not -- they're both built on top of arrays. Stack works just like a list, and Queue is implemented as a ring buffer

Comment: "*If you need to access an item in possibly any place, you must use an Array List*" -- please never use an ArrayList -- they became obsolete when generics were introduced in C# 2. Use a `List<T>`

Comment: Holy fog! I probably got too confident and confused with Java, where Deque and Stack are LinkedLists

Comment: @canton7 List in C# is an array list, or better... an "array-backed list". Source: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs

Comment: "*A Linked List has O(n) access and O(1) in removal*" -- only once you've got a reference to a node. If you need to find the node at a certain index in order to remove it, that's an O(n) operation

Comment: "Array List" refers to [`System.Collections.ArrayList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist?view=net-5.0) in .NET, which is backed by an array, but is non-generic, and was superseded by `List<T>`. Please don't use the term "Array List" to refer to anything else: .NET people will think it refers to `ArrayList`

Comment: Now I understand better, I amended and used "array-backed" list to answer the question from a more CS-oriented point of view.

Answer (score 1):

The logic you're describing don't match a Queue logic, for which the ordering of queued item is the base of the logic.

You can use a standard list for the expected result.

```
List<string> karten = new List<string>();
karten.Add("Karo 11");
karten.Add("Herz 2");
karten.Add("Herz König");
Random r = new Random();
    
while (karten.Count > 0)
{
    int i = r.Next(karten.Count - 1);
    Console.WriteLine(karten[i]);
    karten.RemoveAt(i);
}
```